# how do I check my network users on ubuntu?

Tags: networking

We are using the same network, how can I check the network users group? How can I access their machine with local ip address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two questions.

`how can I check the network users?`

1. Ask your router. Usually the router's address is `192.168.0.1`. You can find out yours by issuing `ip route`. You can normally access a webpage by typing that address in your browser. Look for `DHCP` or `Computers` there. It'll probably ask you for user and password, which depends on the router's make, but is usually `admin`/`admin`.
2. (Easier!) Probe the local ip range and display results. A tool to do that (and much more) is `nmap`. To list all clients on the local network you can issue `nmap -F 192.168.*.*`, although `nmap -F 192.168.0.*` is usually enough for home networks and much, much, faster. If you want to see the operating system of each computer listed, use `nmap -O -F 192.168.0.*` - you'll need root privileges for that.

`How can I access their machine with local ip address?`

As root, initiate `ssh` in both computers: `service ssh start`. Then, from your computer, issue `ssh user@ip`. You now have full access to that user account on that computer. You can use `scp` or `rsync` to copy files between computers, or use software like `samba` to share printers and much more.

Note: In order for a computer to be accessible via `ssh` from **outside** the local network, you'll need to forward port 22 on the router to that computer, and if you have a firewall enabled, add an exception as appropriate.

Comment: what if my OS is different with other machine's OS, can I SSH to other machine's OS?

Comment: Yes, as long as both are running a ssh server.